# How to change the plot legends while mapping a plot command

Tags: plotting, legending, mapthread

I want to change the plot legend in each panel while mapping a plot command. e.g., in the example below

```
ListLinePlot[#,
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[{"48.5 m", "105.5 m", "409.5 m", "508.0 m", "1004.0 m"}, 
     Right]
   ] & /@ RandomReal[10, {5, 500}]
```

I get

[image]

While I want the legends to be 48.5 m, 105.5 m, ....

Answer (score 5):

**Using `MapThread`:**

```
dist = {"48.5 m", "105.5 m", "409.5 m", "508.0 m", "1004.0 m"};
data = RandomReal[10, {5, 500}];

MapThread[
 ListLinePlot[#1
   , PlotLegends -> Placed[{#2}, Right]
   ] &, {data, dist}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are feeding ListLinePlot always the same legend data. You must feed it different legends for each plot. You may achieve this e.g. using MapThread like:

```
MapThread[
 ListLinePlot[#1, PlotLegends -> Placed[#2, Right]] &, {RandomReal[
   10, {5, 500}], {"48.5 m", "105.5 m", "409.5 m", "508.0 m", 
   "1004.0 m"}}]
```

[image]